# Deploying Aurelia.js + io.js/node.js app to heroku Github rate limit problems

Tags: javascript, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, jspm

When deploying a node.js app to heroku, the following error pops up:

> GitHub rate limit reached. To increase the limit use GitHub
>   authentication. remote:              Run jspm registry config github to set this up.

How can I login to github via heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create github access token

   - Go to Github.com, login, settings, personal access tokens
2. Create a personal access token and copy it (we will use it later)

---

1. `$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`
2. Create a .buildpacks file in project root -> where package.json is
3. Add the following buildpacks to it and save and commit

   - https://github.com/timshadel/heroku-buildpack-github-netrc.git
   - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
4. `$ heroku config:set GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN=<Personal Auth Token>`
5. git push heorku deploy:master or git push heorku master

Comment: `https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git` will cease to function soon